# putting unknown number of data from a text file into array/list using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I am reading the airport name and its runway(s) name from a text file and then store them in an array/list for later processing. But in advance I do not know how many runways the airport have. After reading the data into the array/list, I prepare to store them into two columns like this:

```
Airport     Runway
  KPAE        11       //if there is only one runway
```

Or

```
Airport     Runway
  KPAE        11
  KPAE        16R
  KPAE        29
  KPAE        34L      //if there are multiple runways
```

The contents in each column should be from an array/list. What is the proposed way to define the array/list to store the read data. Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be an array or list or can it be another datastructure

Comment: Hi David, it can be another structure - I just want to know how to store them before putting them into columns.

Comment: This is no please-write-me-my-code site... Please try by yourself and if you then encounter a specific problem or error message you are then right to ask for a solution at stack overflow. Please also refer to the FAQ and read "How to ask" and the various other articles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that your best bet is a `Dictionary` like this

```
Dictionary<String, List<String>>
```

Where the `Key` is the airport name and the `Value` is a collection of the runways that the airport has

Answer (score 0):

Yes Dictionary is the best way to tackle as mentioned by David but I want to know do you also want the way of reading data from your text file,Please be specific.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I am trying to use StreamReader for data reading and currently I have not encountered any problem regarding the reading.